# Using wild cards with Type parameter Needs extra casting

Tags: java, generics, casting, comparable

I have created two classes , Parent and child .
My Parent class is implementing Comparable interface 
as "class Parent implements Comparable"

I have also written a method which returns the maximum element of a list ,
here i have ? super T wild card to accept any Child class of Parent .

The following code works fine on a list of Child Objects .

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List <T> list){
    Iterator< T> itr = list.iterator();   // line xx
    T result = itr.next();
    T temp ;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        temp = itr.next();
        if( temp.compareTo(result) > 0)
            result = temp ;
    }
    return result ;
}
```

But if i change the proto type of max method to accept any List of SubType of T by using  < ? extends T >
then the above code does not compile .

> Compliation Error is : cannot convert from Iterator to Iterator

on changing line xx to " Iterator< T> itr = (Iterator) list.iterator();" the code works with < ? extends T > argument .

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List <? extends T> list){
    Iterator< T> itr = (Iterator<T>) list.iterator(); // works fine
    Iterator< T> itr1 =  list.iterator();            // generates compile error .
    T result = itr.next();
    T temp ;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        temp = itr.next();
        if( temp.compareTo(result) > 0)
            result = temp ;
    }
    return result ;
}
```

I am not getting it that why i compile time error is thrown .

Complete Code follows as :

```
package Generics;

import java.util.*;

public class WildCard {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Child> cList = Arrays.asList(new Child("c1"),new Child("c3"),new Child("c2"));
    System.out.println(max(cList));
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T max(List <? extends T> list){
    Iterator< T> itr = (Iterator<T>) list.iterator();
    T result = itr.next();
    T temp ;
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        temp = itr.next();
        if( temp.compareTo(result) > 0)
            result = temp ;
    }
    return result ;
}
}
class Parent implements Comparable<Parent>{
    private String val ;
    public Parent(String val){
        this.val = val ;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Parent o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.val.compareTo(o.val);
    }
    public String toString(){
        return val ;
    }
}
class Child extends Parent{

    public Child(String val) {
        super(val);
    }

}
```

My doubt is even when i was not using ? extends T in function argument , 
i was able to accept the subtypes and i did not need any casting .
But why on changing that syntax i need type casting ?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do have two techniques you can use to avoid the cast. A for-each loop doesn't require a cast, so you can use `for (T t : list)`. You also also use a wildcard in the iterator to avoid a cast: `Iterator<? extends T> itr = list.iterator();`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a `List<? extends T>`, you should use an `Iterator<? extends T>`:

```
Iterator<? extends T> itr = list.iterator();
```

And `Iterator` is a producer of `T` anyway, so according to the PECS rule (Producer `extends`, Consumer `super`), so it's natural that `Iterator` should with `extends` anyway.